# How can I install Parsero?

Tags: command-line

When I try to download a tool or package I get this error

```
root@A6670:~# apt-get install parsero
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package parsero
```

Comment: That's correct - there is no package named `parsero` in the Ubuntu repositories. Perhaps you intend to be looking someplace else?

Comment: parsero seems to be a package for Kali linux - perhaps that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you using Kali since you [previously tagged](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1116445/1) your question with "kali-linux-tools" tag?

Answer (score 2):

Please try installing via pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install parsero
```

Comment: That's a valid answer, not a comment. Comments help improve the question.